# После нескольких нажатий на bottomNavigation перестает отображатся View определенного фрагмента

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

MainActivity:

Проблема в том, что после нескольких переходов по трем фрагментам (примерно после 3 - х переходов), view фрагмента остается на фоне, то есть не меняется, приложение при этом не падает, память не растет (используемая, проверял в студии).

Использую cicerone для перемещения по фрагментам

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.certificationItem:
            router.replaceScreen(FragmentScreenKeys.FRAGMENT_CERTIFICATION);
            return true;
        case R.id.planItem:
            router.replaceScreen(FragmentScreenKeys.FRAGMENT_PLAN);
            return true;
        case R.id.chatItem:
            router.replaceScreen(FragmentScreenKeys.FRAGMENT_CHAT);
            return true;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown item.getId");
    }
}
```

Fragment1:

```
private View view;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getComponent().inject(this);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_certification, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    holder.setNavigator(navigator);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    holder.removeNavigator();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    view = null;
}

@Override
public Fragment newInstance() {
    return new FragmentCertification();
}
```

Fragment2:

```
private View view;
private LearningAdapter adapter;

@Inject
ApiService apiService;

@BindView(R.id.recyclerPlan) RecyclerView recyclerPlan;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getComponent().inject(this);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plan, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    initRecycler(view);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showLearning();
}

private void initRecycler(View view){
    recyclerPlan.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(),
            OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false));
}

private void showLearning(){
    adapter = new LearningAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
    recyclerPlan.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    view = null;
}

@Override
public Fragment newInstance() {
    return new FragmentPlan();
}
```

Fragment3:

```
private View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    view = null;
}

@Override
public Fragment newInstance() {
    return new FragmentChat();
}
```

И навигатор:

```
public MainNavigator(FragmentActivity activity, int containerId) {
    super(activity, containerId);
}

@Override
protected Intent createActivityIntent(Context context, String screenKey, Object data) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment(String screenKey, Object data) {
    switch (screenKey){
        case FragmentScreenKeys.FRAGMENT_CERTIFICATION:
            return new FragmentCertification().newInstance();
        case FragmentScreenKeys.FRAGMENT_PLAN:
            return new FragmentPlan().newInstance();
        case FragmentScreenKeys.FRAGMENT_CHAT:
            return new FragmentChat().newInstance();
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown screen key");
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. Хотя, скорей всего, такое может быть из-за `onDestroyView()` или `onPause()`. Пробуйте без этих методов.

Comment: @RomanShubenko то что в onDestroy() я добавил после, думал, что может view не удаляется, установка null на нее поможет, не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалил методы o`nPause()` and `onDestroyView()`

В первом фрагменте использовал `cicerone`, хотя он там был не нужен, который подключал свой навигатор в методе `onResume()` и отписывался от него в методе `onPause()` - удалил их, тоже самое и в других фргаментах. Решило проблему.

Но в проекте есть еще тройка фрагментов, в которых `cicerone` использутся, и его навигаторы, методы `onResume()` and `onPause()` присутствуют, но никакой проблемы с ними нет.